# Conditional mutate depending on if value is higher/lower than total

Tags: r

I have a table similar to this:

| Area | Value | Lower Interval | Upper Interval |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AreaA | 2 | 1.2 | 2.4 |
| AreaB | 11 | 10.7 | 11.6 |
| AreaC | 30 | 15.2 | 16.6 |
| Total | 12 | 11.2 | 12.5 |

I am looking to add a mutate column at the end called 'Significance' which has 3 conditions:

'Lower' if the upper interval for each area is below the lower interval for the total
'Same' if the confidence intervals between the areas and the grand total overlaps and
'Higher' if the lower interval for each area is below the upper interval for the total.

So in this instance the end result would look like this:

| Area | Value | Lower Interval | Upper Interval | Significance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AreaA | 2 | 1.2 | 2.4 | Lower |
| AreaB | 11 | 10.7 | 11.6 | Same |
| AreaC | 30 | 15.2 | 16.6 | Higher |
| Total | 12 | 11.2 | 12.5 | - |

Could anyone please advise on how to take this forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `case_when` from `tidyverse` to make several `ifelse` statements. For the sake of not having repetitive code, I pulled out the low and high values from the total.

```
library(tidyverse)

low <- df %>% filter(Area == "Total") %>% pull("LowerInterval")
high <- df %>% filter(Area == "Total") %>% pull("UpperInterval")

df %>% 
  mutate(Significance = case_when(Area == "Total" ~ "-",
                                   UpperInterval < low ~ "Lower",
                                   between(LowerInterval, low, high) | between(UpperInterval, low, high) ~ "Same",
                                   LowerInterval > high ~ "Higher",
                                   TRUE ~ NA_character_))
```

**Output**

```
   Area Value LowerInterval UpperInterval Significance
1 AreaA     2           1.2           2.4        Lower
2 AreaB    11          10.7          11.6         Same
3 AreaC    30          15.2          16.6       Higher
4 Total    12          11.2          12.5            -
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Area = c("AreaA", "AreaB", "AreaC", "Total"), 
    Value = c(2L, 11L, 30L, 12L), LowerInterval = c(1.2, 10.7, 
    15.2, 11.2), UpperInterval = c(2.4, 11.6, 16.6, 12.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Thanks that's great, can't thank you enough.